# Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture doesn't return country correctly

Tags: c#, localization, cultureinfo, culture, currentuiculture

I'm with a very strange problem. I am implementing localization on my project, but when I try to get the current locale Windows is running, it misses the country information. Here it is a sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
      Console.WriteLine("The current UI culture is {0} [{1}]",
                        culture.NativeName, culture.Name);
   }
}
```

When I run it in the most common languages (En-US, FR-fr), it returns correctly. However, when I select French from Belgium, for instance, it retrieves me FR-fr instead of FR-be - even if I delete French from France from the language preference options.

I wonder how could I get the country I selected correctly all the time, no matter which country my software is located.

ps: Using CurrentCulture isn't the answer I'm looking for, since I want a match to the display language I'm using in my UI, not to date/time/number formats (they can be totally different).

Comment: I've just tried to uninstall French language pack (FR-fr) and install back selecting it from French Belgium. I still get FR-fr. Would that be an Windows issue?

Comment: Crystal ball says that you selected another keyboard layout instead of changing the operating system language.  You'll have to use the "Advanced" button.  Very unclear what you actually did, probably best to ping this at superuser.com first.  Be sure to mention the Windows version and edition, they changed this in about every release and what language packs you have installed matter a lot.

Comment: I tested in Windows 8 and 10. None of them works. I changed the OS language - installed language packs and stuff like that (you can only do that on the Advanced session), just as I mentioned on the previous comment.

Comment: I'm not activelly looking for an answer to this anymore - I'm not working on this project, neither with C# anymore. However, if anyone finds an answer to this (or useful information), I'm still curious and I'm willing to check if it would fit to that project...

Answer (score 1):

I think than you have wrong using in header.

MS use system.thread and not system.globalization
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentuiculture(v=vs.110).aspx
In some of these there are compilation errors.

The correct and compiling code is this:

(notice as CultureInfo.CurrentCulture is readonly, instead i've used System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture that has setter accessible)

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Display the name of the current thread culture.
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentCulture is {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

    // Change the current culture to th-TH.
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("th-TH", false);
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentCulture is now {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

    // Display the name of the current UI culture.
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentUICulture is {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

    // Change the current UI culture to ja-JP.
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ja-JP", false);
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentUICulture is now {0}.", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);

}
```

Comment: System.Globalization is required for CultureInfo class. And all the examples on the link you posted use System.Globalization.

Comment: sorry, i've read it on phone and never tried it. I've found errors on examples. I've added correct info

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to change the current culture, nor current UI culture programatically. I just want to get the correct language/country information from the OS - which, in case of belgium french, comes incorrectly. The code you posted doesn't add anything new from the code I`ve posted but the change culture requests.

Comment: i understand than you didn't want to change CurrentCulture, i've found another entry point to the "CurrentCulture" how is explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture.aspx. So they have the same values?   I've found also more interesting here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx, where there are detailed information about "CurrentCulture" is depending on thread and main thread.

Comment: Thanks for the links. However, they still doesn't solve my problem. It might be a corner case, but it is possible that the CurrentCulture (Region, currency configuration) and CurrentUICulture (OS ui language) don't match (I use very often the OS in english and currency in other locale). And, when I get the thread's CurrentUICulture whithout programatically changing it, it comes as FR-fr instead of FR-be (if I change it in the code, it comes with the value set). I wonder if this is some sort of OS limitation, since French language packs seems to be the same for FR-fr and FR-be.